# Any Link in bootstrap 4 modal can not use anymore

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I don't know what happened but I build a modal for Shopping-Cart Page.
When I try to click the title of Item in modal, and the modal will hide and link can not affect as normal. I don't know **why** and **how to solve it**.
It makes me so frustrated.

My Bootstrap4 Version is 4.1.3
Is this bug caused by this version?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="modalCart" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="document">
  <div class="modal-dialog bg-light" role="document">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title text-center"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart pr-1"></i>購物車</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form class="form-group">
        <div class="media cart-item mt-3 mb-3">
          <a href="/product.html"><img class="mr-3" src="img/NOIMAGE.png" style="width: 120px; height: auto;"></a>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h5 class="mt-0"><a href="/product.html">商品1</a></h5>
            <div class="price-group">
              <div class="form-inline">
                <span class="price mr-1" style="width: 4em;">500元</span>
                <span class="multiple mr-4"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                <div class="input-group mr-2">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#"><i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i></a>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1" style="width: 5em; text-align: center;">
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">關閉購物車</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down pr-1"></i>結帳</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/220091/ Like it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `modal-content` level. [It should be structured](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/) in the following way (schematically):

```
.modal
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
       .modal-header
       .modal-body
       .modal-footer
```

And you did it like this:

```
.modal
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-header
    .modal-body
    .modal-footer
```

When you fix html structure everything will work fine.